# CorePlot: bring grid lines to the foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, graph, core-plot, tvos

Just like the title says, is there a way to bring grid lines into foreground (namely, in front of the graph, but behind symbols)? What I have right now is:

[image]

And my code is as follows (using **Swift 3**):

```
    let gridLineStyle = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    gridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.75
    gridLineStyle.lineColor = CPTColor.white()

    let bottomXAxis = axisSet.axis(for: .X, at: 0)  as! CPTXYAxis
    bottomXAxis.labelingPolicy = .none
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0
    bottomXAxis.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle
    bottomXAxis.majorTickLength = 4.0
    bottomXAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 0
    bottomXAxis.labelTextStyle = axisTitleStyle
    bottomXAxis.labelOffset = -2.0
    bottomXAxis.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle
```

Answer (score 1):

Plot symbols are drawn in the same layer as the scatter plot. You can rearrange the drawing layers with the [`topDownLayerOrder`](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_plot_area.html#a506fba7759eff65695ca5a7be253176f), but that still keeps the plots together.

One possible solution is to use a partially transparent fill for the area fills under the scatter plots. That would allow the grid line to show through. Another solution would be to draw your own grid lines with another scatter plot. Use separate plots to draw the fills, the grid, and the plot symbols so you can control the layering.

Comment: thank you, that is what I figured i would need to do - multiple plots, but was still hoping there is a way...